# No funciona el SweetAlert en PHP

Tags: php, sweetalert, alert

Estoy teniendo problemas porque el sweetalert no me funciona en mi archivo PHP.

El código original que escribí es el siguiente:

```
echo '<script> alert("ESTAS INSCRITO");</script>';
```

Pero el que quiero que me muestre pero no funciona es este código:

```
echo '<script> Swal.fire({ icon: "success", title: "ESTAS INSCRITO"});</script>';
```

Comment: [Lectura recomendada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152/263200)

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería funcionar si cuando haces el `echo` lo estás mandando a un bloque `<script></script>`  (sino agrégalo en el `echo`). Y asegúrate que cargas la libreria antes de usarlo.

Ejemplo:

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script>
Swal.fire({ icon: "success", title: "ESTAS INSCRITO"});
</script>
```

Desde PHP sería así (de forma completa):

```
echo '
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script>
  Swal.fire({ icon: "success", title: "ESTAS INSCRITO"});
</script>
';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo intentaré. 

Saludos.